# Why the response is 400 when using the same headers with python requests?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape this website: https://segari.id/c/unggas.

I tried using requests:

```
url="https://api-v2.segari.id/v1.1/products/price?agentId=311&tagIds=838&size=999&page=0&paginationType=slice&totalPriceBefore=0&deliveryDate=2023-10-26&deliveryServiceType=NEXT_DAY_DELIVERY&pageOrigin=clp"

headers={
    'Referer':'https://segari.id/',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua':'"Chromium";v="118", "Google Chrome";v="118", "Not=A?Brand";v="99"',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile':'?0',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform': '"Windows"',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest':'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode':'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site':'same-site',
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'X-Segari-Pathname':'/c/unggas',
    'X-Segari-Platform':'web',
    'X-Segari-Sec': 'v1:MjAyMy0xMC0yNVQxMzoxODozNS40OTQwMDArMDc6MDA=:96a10a8bbb9f47b8cfb1db7bd3ad483632ede18b0631de80e9720e30d4928f07'
}
 
response=requests.get(url,headers=headers)

#response returns <Response [400]>
#response.content returns message":"04 - Signature Mismatch","code":"TODO","data":null,"errors":null
```

I tried opening the API URL, and returns error. I checked that X-segari-sec is the only thing missing in the header. So I deduced that's the only missing thing. I also noticed a request to 'https://api-v2.segari.id/v1/util/server-time'. I tried the X-segari-sec by emulating the JavaScript. It's the same.

Here's the python for it

```py
def get_X_segar_sec(hash_key, timestamp):
  
  hash_key = "wCL8iD2xgQ5EdLrVBEYvAP3nRxX3q6TSNjIlISOx7PTphdhA78M2cjlN5RISAHwn"

  base64_encoded_timestamp = base64.b64encode(timestamp.encode()).decode()
  hash_string = f"{hash_key}{base64_encoded_timestamp}"
  hash_value = hashlib.sha256(hash_string.encode()).hexdigest()

  return f"v1:{base64_encoded_timestamp}:{hash_value}"
```

The response is 400 and returns a mismatch text from content.
Can someone help me to get 200? Why is this happening? I tried using selenium too and no data is being loaded after waiting.

This is the selenium code:

```py
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    
    driver.get('https://segari.id/c/susu-olahansusu')
    
    # Define a function to scroll to the bottom of the page
    def scroll_to_bottom():
        # Use JavaScript to scroll to the bottom
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    
    # Scroll down in a loop until reaching the bottom
    scroll_delay = 2  # Adjust as needed
    while True:
        previous_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        scroll_to_bottom()
        time.sleep(scroll_delay)
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == previous_height:
          break
```

*Update*: it's returning something, but not what it is supposed to be seen in the screen. I am trying to capture the cookies and pass it in the API above.

Through

```py
cookies = driver.get_cookies()

# Create a new Requests Session object
session = Session()

# Add the cookies to the Requests Session object
for cookie in cookies:
    session.cookies.set(cookie['name'], cookie['value'])
```

Comment: First that isn't valid python. Your dictionary is unclosed. Also, please share debugging details, like the traceback.

Comment: hi thank you for correcting the mistake. with the above the response is <Response [400]> .  response.content is "message":"04 - Signature Mismatch","code":"TODO","data":null,"errors":null . I emulated by opening a session, then getting the headers from options before passing the hashed date_time_string= into the header above.

Comment: If the server answers with a different code, either the request is not exactly the same, or some field are expected to match a server session value.

Comment: I tried opening the api url, and deduce that from headers missing is the  X-segari-sec. I checked that there's a request to get server time. Tried passing that too and it does not work. Any ideas on what is passed to server?

Comment: Your request header is missing all the cookies generated from the JavaScript code. If those cookies are indeed required by the server in order to produce a valid response you'd better use a browser-based web scraping tool such as [`selenium`](https://www.selenium.dev/) instead since it's going to be incredibly tricky to generate those cookies dynamically without a proper JavaScript engine.

Comment: Hi i tried selenium too, i tried for it to wait until picture loads, however it always times out. Is there a way around this? I will try to generate all the missing cookies from the javascript needed.

Comment: @Hal In that case your selenium code should be your best attempt so far at the problem. Please update the question with your selenium code so we can help troubleshoot why it is stuck.

Comment: Updated with selenium. either way I think waiting is not the issue here.

Comment: sounds like it's a TOTP: Time-based one-time password.   Which implies you need to authenticate yourself.  The TOTP may be generated when an authenticated session is created.  You should authenticate yourself using Selenium.  No need to read/set cookies, they'll be set/sent automatically.

Comment: then the next question is when using selenium, the data retrieved is different from the one we see on the web. I am wondering why is that so?As of TOTP, i am guessing it is using the timeserver api and hashing it into x_segar_sec_id. that makes sense

Comment: Signature mismatch errors typically mean you're not replicating the site's API security checks correctly. Check their terms or contact them for API access. Ensure Selenium captures all cookies for requests properly.

Comment: how to ensure selenium captures all cookies for requests?

Answer (score 0):

400 errors are defined by standard as user correctable.

That being said the server is free to offer any error it wants.

One of the scripts on the page is asking for something not provided by selenium: possibilities include HD free space, memory amount, screen size, or native code execution.

I would suggest using a full browser based solution such as Puppeteer to scrape the data.

This will be slower but should work, just as long as request limits(minimum time and count) are not exceeded.